# How to insert multi-line string into other string in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell-2.0 script

```
$FailedTests = Get-ChildItem $PathLog | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select name
"+++"
$FailedTests
"+++"

$Text = "
Summary
----------
$FailedTests
"
$Text
"+++"
```

and the generated output is:

```
+++

Name : Test1


Name : Test2

+++

Summary
----------


+++
```

which looks absolutely unlogic to me. I have expected the following output:

```
+++

Name : Test1


Name : Test2

+++

Summary
----------


Name : Test1


Name : Test2

+++
```

What is going on? How to fix this?

Maybe `$FailedTests` is not a string? So, what is it? How to convert this into a string?

Comment: Do you have a typo in the variable name? (not in the code you posted, but in the code you tested)

Comment: I have not, but my guess is that $FailedTests is not a string. Let me update the question

Comment: There you have it. And that's why you should always post the complete, relevant code.

Comment: So it this a list? The documentation does not help here: "The type of object that Get-ChildItem returns is determined by the objects in the provider drive path. " No idea what that means ...

Comment: How can I include a sample? I do not know what `$FailedTests` actually is, so how to include it...?

Comment: You can use `$FailedTests.GetType()` or `$FailedTests | Get-Member` (shows objects inside if array) to find out what types your objects are. Or you could show how `$FailedTests` was created in the first place. If it's from known cmdlet we may be able to find documentation etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105434/discussion-between-alex-and-frode-f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$FailedTests` are not strings, but some other kind of objects. Your code is currently something like this:

```
$FailedTests = [pscustomobject]@{ Name = "Test1"},[pscustomobject]@{ Name = "Test2"}

#I had to use `Format-List *` to output the sample-objects in the same format as your objects.
#The default format are diferent between different types of objects

"+++"
$FailedTests | Format-List *
"+++"

$Text = "
Summary
----------
$FailedTests
"
$Text
"+++"
```

Output:

```
+++


Name : Test1

Name : Test2



+++

Summary
----------


+++
```

The objects `ToString()` doesn't output anything. The easiest solution is to use `| Out-String` to convert the format you get in the console to a string. This would require a subexpression `$()`. Ex:

```
$FailedTests = [pscustomobject]@{ Name = "Test1"},[pscustomobject]@{ Name = "Test2"}

"+++"
$FailedTests | Format-List *
"+++"

$Text = "
Summary
----------
$($FailedTests | Format-List * | Out-String)
"
$Text
"+++"
```

Ouptut:

```
+++


Name : Test1

Name : Test2



+++

Summary
----------


Name : Test1

Name : Test2





+++
```

Comment: `$FailedTests` is NOT an array! Not sure what it is, but `GetType()` say `IsArray   :   False`

Comment: No reason to be angry. You have provided us with an unclear question and incomplete sample. After you updated the sample with `$FailedTests = Get-childitem` you actually defined `$FailesTests` as an array which made the sample invalid since the sample and output was not matching. We can only guess when you don't tell us. I would suggest reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not sure what was unclear in my question, nut its good we agree that the object is some object and not an array. Now I cannot ask another question... On how to actually get an array if directory names! But I guess this is outside the scope of this question and I have to wait 24 hours to ask my question. To bad...

Comment: Your question was unclear because we had no idea what type of objects we were working with. An answer for an object might not work for an array, hashtable/dictionary etc. Again, read the link. We need to have enough details to be able to reproduce the problem to be able to provide a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$FailedTests` is an array. You can check that with `$FailedTests.GetType()`.

The problem is, that objects get passed on to some output commandlet like `Format-Table` if you put them in a separate statement, but not if you put them in quotes.

Easiest solution: don't build your output in such a convoluted way.

```
$FailedTests = Get-ChildItem $PathLog | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select name

"+++"
$FailedTests
"+++"

"Summary
----------"
$FailedTests
"+++"
```

Comment: I need the output in ONE variable to be able to send an email. Your solution won't work for me...

Comment: You should write your requirements in the question.

Comment: But you expect people to help you. And by not giving all the necessary information in the first place, you waste everybodys time.

Comment: Not everybodys... I will try to be more precise next time, spending 10 hours to formulate my question so clear it is beyond any uncertainty....

Comment: `$FailedTests` does not seem to be an array! `GetType()` say `IsArray  :  False`...